# How to download content of an element by its hierarchy

Tags: c#, html, dom, html-agility-pack

I'm new to stackoverflow and I hope my question not be odd..

I want to just download the text inside `svalue` of `sindex` element, and also content of another `<p>` tag. This is its hierarchy:

```
/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table[4]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/span/span/p/span/sindex
```

is it possible to download the content by its hierarchy? with HtmlAgilityPack for example, or in another way?

Thanks

---

```
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string url = "http://www.google.com";
    var content = client.DownloadString(url);

    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(content);
    // ?
```

**Update** after @MSI answer, I Use this:

```
    var value = doc.DocumentNode
        .SelectSingleNode("//html/body/div/div/a/div");
```

But the return value always is null. mayber I get the hierarchy in a wrong way. I use firebug and look at html tab for its hierarchy, is it wrong?

Comment: what do the docs/examples say?

Comment: I didn't saw any documentation and just one example for agility.. but anyway if there is another way, I appreciate it.

Comment: Please post your html on pastebin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you use something along the line of,

*Considering svalue to be an attribute:

```
doc.DocumentNode
    .SelectSingleNode("//html/element1/element2")
    .Attributes["svalue"].Value;
```

or for element,

```
doc.DocumentNode
    .SelectSingleNode("//html/element1/element2/svalue").InnerText;
```

**EDIT**:

Re. SelectSingleNode returning null for my previous examples with google.com.au as reference HTML source use the following method to et the desired result.

```
doc.DocumentNode
    .SelectSingleNode(".//element1/element2/svalue").InnerText;
```

DocumentNode should refer to the html document root node and .// is relative to that.

Comment: Hi, Whenever I use SelectSingleNode, the return value is null. I download and load the page this way, maybe it is wrong? `webClient.DownloadFile(url, "downloaded.htm");` and `doc.LoadHtml("downloaded.htm");`

Comment: You could also use WebClient.DownloadString() and feed the string directly to AgilityPack's LoadHtml.